# TypeScript errors only appear on first Webpack compile

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack

I'm learning about TypeScript and getting it set up is giving me difficulties.
If I add a syntax error or something, then startup the `webpack-dev-server`, compilation will fail, but if I save and get the server to recompile the error goes away. Errors added while the dev server is already running also do not get picked up. It appears that

`webpack-dev-server` initial output

```
yarn run v1.22.10
$ npx webpack-dev-server --config goal_tracker/webpack/dev.config.js
ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:3000/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /static/
ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /home/sean/sourcecode/goal_tracker
✖ ｢wdm｣: asset main.js 3.69 MiB [emitted] (name: main)
runtime modules 24.8 KiB 13 modules
modules by path ./node_modules/ 1.35 MiB 70 modules
modules by path ./client/ 8.15 KiB
  modules by path ./client/apps/common/ 2.99 KiB
    modules by path ./client/apps/common/*.ts 415 bytes 3 modules
    modules by path ./client/apps/common/hooks/*.ts 2.58 KiB 3 modules
  modules by path ./client/apps/tests/ 5.13 KiB
    modules by path ./client/apps/tests/styles/*.scss 2.1 KiB
      ./client/apps/tests/styles/main.scss 1.44 KiB [built] [code generated]
      ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./client/apps/tests/styles/main.scss 680 bytes [built] [code generated]
    ./client/apps/tests/index.tsx 1.28 KiB [built] [code generated]
    ./client/apps/tests/users/register.tsx 1.75 KiB [built] [code generated]
  ./client/packs/tests.ts 38 bytes [built] [code generated] [1 error]

ERROR in /home/sean/sourcecode/goal_tracker/client/packs/tests.ts
./client/packs/tests.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /home/sean/sourcecode/goal_tracker/client/packs/tests.ts(2,1)
      TS2304: Cannot find name 'isNotDefined'.

webpack 5.3.2 compiled with 1 error in 4725 ms
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

Output after saving a file, but not removing the issue

```
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiling...
ℹ ｢wdm｣: asset main.js 3.69 MiB [emitted] (name: main)
runtime modules 24.8 KiB 13 modules
modules by path ./node_modules/ 1.35 MiB 70 modules
modules by path ./client/ 8.15 KiB
  modules by path ./client/apps/common/ 2.99 KiB
    modules by path ./client/apps/common/*.ts 415 bytes 3 modules
    modules by path ./client/apps/common/hooks/*.ts 2.58 KiB 3 modules
  modules by path ./client/apps/tests/ 5.13 KiB
    modules by path ./client/apps/tests/styles/*.scss 2.1 KiB
      ./client/apps/tests/styles/main.scss 1.44 KiB [built] [code generated]
      ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./client/apps/tests/styles/main.scss 680 bytes [built] [code generated]
    ./client/apps/tests/index.tsx 1.28 KiB [built] [code generated]
    ./client/apps/tests/users/register.tsx 1.75 KiB [built] [code generated]
  ./client/packs/tests.ts 38 bytes [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.3.2 compiled successfully in 1977 ms
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

My webpack config

```js
const path = require("path")

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  bail: true,
  cache: false,
  entry: "./client/packs/tests.ts",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve("./client/static/client/js"),
    filename: "[name].js",
    chunkFilename: "[id]-[chunkhash].js",
    publicPath: "/static/",
  },
  devServer: {
    overlay: true,
    port: 3000,
    hot: true,
    compress: true,
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: "ts-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          "style-loader",
          "css-loader",
          "sass-loader",
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js"],
  },
  devtool: "inline-source-map",
};
```

My tsconfig

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es5",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "outDir": "./client/static/client/js/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strict": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false
  },
  "exclude": ["**/*.spec.ts", "node_modules", "vendor", "public"],
  "compileOnSave": false
}
```

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: Do You have only one tsconfig.json file?

Comment: @captain-yossarian, just the one

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it!
I found out that I was using a globally installed version of webpack-dev-server and for some reason that was causing the issue, so I just added it to the `package.json` and installed it. Works fine now